# Repeating and Changing php values for my Music Player

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timer, repeat

I would like to know how i can change or repeat certain elements in php.
Right now i am using a script to fetch what song is playing from a shout-cast info page.

And in JQuery i have a player with a playlist that switches stream.

Now the only thing it does right now is just switch to the stream and not display anything.
So how would i go about on calling an php part inside jQuery?

Gosh, i really hope im being clear enough in my explanation.

For those who are able to help me

**What parts of my code do you want me to display?**

i wil then go ahead and paste that for you Right away! :)

Greets,

Kus.

Code for Arjan:
JQUery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container"
    }, [
        {
        title: "test",
        mp3: "http://178.156.201.212:8018/;stream/1",
        <?php
        $host = "178.156.201.212"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
        $port = "8018";
        ?>
        },
        {
        title: "test2",
        mp3: "http://stream1.slowradio.com/;stream/1",
        <?php
        $host = "http://stream1.slowradio.com"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
        $port = "8008";
        ?>
        },
        {
        title: "test3",
        mp3: "http://108.61.73.119:8022/;stream/1",
        <?php
        $host = "108.61.73.119"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
        $port = "8022";
        ?>
        },
    ], {
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });

    $("#jquery_jplayer").bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function(event) {       
        //$('#fetch').html(jPlayerPlaylist.playlist[jPlayerPlaylist.current].title);
        $('#fetch').empty();
        $('#fetch').append(myPlaylist.playlist[myPlaylist.current].title);  
    });

});
```

PHP

```
<?php



$host = "178.156.201.212"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
$port = "8000";          // port of shoutcast server 

$fp = @fsockopen("$host", $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if($fp)
{
  fputs($fp,"GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: GET SEVEN (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");

  while(!feof($fp))
  {
    $data .= fgets($fp, 1000);
  }

  fclose($fp);

  $data              = ereg_replace(".*<body>", "", $data);
  $data              = ereg_replace("</body>.*", ",", $data);
  $data_array        = explode(",",$data);
  $listeners         = $data_array[0];
  $status            = $data_array[1];
  $peak_listeners    = $data_array[2];
  $maximum_listeners = $data_array[3];
  $unique_listeners  = $data_array[4];
  $bitrate           = $data_array[5];
  $track             = $data_array[6];
}

$title  = chop($track);
$select = explode(" - ",$title);
$artist = chop($select[0]);
$title  = chop($select[1]);

?> 




<?php
if($status == 1)
{
    echo $artist. " - " .$title;
}
else
{
  print 'document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Offline";';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling PHP inside jquery is done by this code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'this_file.php',
success: function(html) {   
   var data = html.split(' ');
   var host = data[0];
   var port = data[1];
}
});
```

Your PHP would be:

```
if ( isset($_GET['update']) ) {
  die($host.' '.$port);
}
```

This code loads html from the php file and puts it in the HTML body tag. Ofcourse you can change body to any element.

For more specific help, post some of your PHP and jQuery code please.

Edit: Full documentation on: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Cool i will have a try with this TY VERY MUCH. I will let you how it went ASAP! Ty very much! ^^

Comment: One question though.. I have this inside my current page. How would i fetch it if i kept it in there instead of having it in a seperate php page? cause the php function is pretty big and i dont wanna constantly have that big part repeating. i would like to have it repeat it but with different variables. they are defined like so $host = "info here"; $port = "port info here";

Comment: I added it in now. Sorry that it took an hour :/ ~ I was just trying stuff for half an hour and then i had to go away for another half hour and help someone.

Comment: So what im trying is to have it work when i switch stream. Like i switch the title at the moment when i do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
<?php
    $host = "http://stream1.slowradio.com"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
    $port = "8008";
?>
```

Has to be

```
<?php
    $host = "http://stream1.slowradio.com"; // ip or url of shoutcast server
    $port = "8008";
    echo 'host: '.$host;
    echo 'port: '.$port;
?>
```

Next time, make sure you give your code right away. That saves a lot of time and downvotes I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much Arjan, i dont think there is a next time though.. it says im not allowed to ask questions anymore O_O' ....

Is there someway i could contact you? I did some more learning on php while we were both gone. And i learnd some more about custom functions and calling them.. But now i have the problem that i cant have it call from the playlist. If you get what im saying? Thank you so much for the help btw.

Comment: I did what you said above. But it doesn't change when i go to the next stream.

Comment: so my idea was to make it a function with the host and port in that.
But i placed it in the umm playlist of JQuery but i dont know how to make it call when i switch stream like the title does. i tried to use the same code but pfff.. getting confused heh sorry.

Comment: @Kus I think you're working a bit above your capacity right now. What you want to do is a little bit complicated for beginners in web development. You can e-mail me of course, see profile.

Comment: Hi @Arjan i looked inside your profile but i cant find your email there =o

Or anything like "Send Message".. Is it because i am not high ranked user here? Or am i not seeing something?